# best practice? referencing posts within queries

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to pull two random posts with meta value 1, and one random post with meta value 2, and arrange those in a loop as: 121

The script below functions fine. But, I believe it could be more efficiently executed. The function could also, theoretically, pull the same post for the args1a and args1b queries.

Is there some sort of way to reference say the first and second results of args1 (if I were to do showposts=>2) and then call those in a new query? This way I could avoid having two separate queries for essentially the same arguments.

```
$args1a = array(
    'meta_key' => 'key',
    'meta_value' => '1',
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'showposts' => 1,
);
$args1b = array(
    'meta_key' => 'key',
    'meta_value' => '1',
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'showposts' => 1,
);
$args2 = array(
    'meta_key' => 'key',
    'meta_value' => '2',
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'showposts' => 1,
);

$args1a_query = new WP_Query( $args1a );
$args1b_query = new WP_Query( $args1b );
$args2_query = new WP_Query( $args2 );
$loop = new WP_Query();
$loop->posts = array_merge( $args1a_query->posts, $args2_query->posts, $args1b_query->posts);
$loop->post_count = count( $loop->posts );
if ($loop->have_posts()) :
while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
```

edit: here is the finalized, working code with ROunofF's solutions (edited out a few errors)

```
$args1a = array(
    'meta_key' => 'key',
    'meta_value' => '1',
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'showposts' => 2,
);
$args2 = array(
    'meta_key' => 'key',
    'meta_value' => '2',
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'showposts' => 1,
);

$args1_query = new WP_Query( $args1 );
$args2_query = new WP_Query( $args2 );
$loop = new WP_Query();
$remainingPosts = array_splice($args1_query->posts, 1, 1, $args2_query->posts);
$loop->posts = array_merge($args1_query->posts, $remainingPosts);
$loop->post_count = count( $loop->posts );
if ($loop->have_posts()) :
while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - So to solve this you want to get 2 posts from your "args1_query" by using 'showposts' => 2.

2 - Then just replace your array_merge by code below (Steps explained in comment):

```
// Initially
// $args1_query->posts = [1a, 1b]
// $args2_query->posts = [2a]

$remainingPost = array_splice($args1_query->posts, 1, 1, $args2_query->posts);

// After splice (offset: 1, length: 1; so we replaced 1b by the content of args2_query_posts):
// $args1_query->posts = [1a, 2a]
// $remainingPost = [1b]

$loop->posts = array_merge($args1_query->posts, $remainingPosts);

// After merge
// $loop_posts = [1a, 2a, 1b]
```

The splice method allows to replace some content (extract) of an array by another array and return the extracted content.

3 - Profit ?

Comment: awesome, thanks a ton! when you have a sec could you please explain the array splice function in this application?

also, args1 and arg2 in those two lines should be args1_query and args2_query, and the two remainingPost variables do not match

Comment: I corrected my typos, sorry for that. The splice method allows to replace the content of an array by another and extract the replaced content.